# Compare and get difference from two object for patch api request in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i m having two objects previous and new one, i trying  to compare and get difference for those objects, send to as patch payload from patch api,

compare each properties in object if any of the property has any difference i want all those difference in new object as payload

How can i achieve this please help me find the solution?
Is there any `lodash` method for this solution?

```
let obj = {
  Name: "Ajmal",
  age: 25,
  email: "ajmaln@gmail.com",
  contact: [12345678, 987654321],
  address: {
    houseName: "ABC",
    street: "XYZ",
    pin: 67891
  }
}
```

[image: previous object]

```
let obj2 = {
  Name: "Ajmal",
  age: 25,
  email: "something@gmail.com",
  contact: [12345678, 11111111],
  address: {
    houseName: "ABC",
    street: "XYZ",
    pin: 111
  }
}
```

[image: new object]

[image: object 1 and object 2]

result payload i m  expecting would look like

```
let payload = {
  email: "something@gmail.com",
  contact: [12345678, 11111111],
  address: {
    pin: 111
  }
}
```

Comment: why it takes `contact` of `obj2`? What rule should be there?

Comment: There is no easy answer. You basically will need to make a function that compares two objects which can contain complex nested data, to see if there is any difference.

Comment: Didn't get you?

Answer (score 0):

Mista NewbeedRecursion to your service:

```
const compare = (obj1, obj2) => {
  const keys = Object.keys(obj1);

  const payload = {};

  keys.forEach((el) => {
    const first = obj1[el];
    const second = obj2[el];
    let check;
    if (first !== second) {
      if (first instanceof Object && !(first instanceof Array))
        check = compare(first, second);
      payload[el] = check || second;
    }
  });
  return payload;
};
```

Comment: what if contacts contain array of object
 contact: [{primary:12345678}, {secondary:111111111}]
result -> contact : [{secondary: 111111111}]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a approach with immer that may guide you to a proper solution
This is not a generic approach but makes things easier by relying on [immer](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/patches/)

```
import produce, { applyPatches, enablePatches } from "immer";
import { difference } from "lodash";

// once in your app
enablePatches();

let obj = {
  Name: "Ajmal",
  age: 25,
  email: "ajmaln@gmail.com",
  contact: [12345678, 987654321],
  address: {
    houseName: "ABC",
    street: "XYZ",
    pin: 67891
  }
};

let obj2 = {
  Name: "Ajmal",
  age: 25,
  email: "something@gmail.com",
  contact: [12345678, 11111111],
  address: {
    houseName: "ABC",
    street: "XYZ",
    pin: 111
  }
};
```

Gettig the patch updates

```
 let fork = { ...obj };
    let changes = [];

    const updatedItem = produce(
      fork,
      (draft) => {

        // object specific updates
        draft.Name = obj2.Name;
        draft.age = obj2.age;
        draft.email = obj2.email;
        draft.address.houseName = obj2.address.houseName;
        draft.address.street = obj2.address.street;
        draft.address.pin = obj2.address.pin;
       const originalContact = original(draft.contact);
       const contactDiff = difference(obj2.contact, originalContact);
       console.log("diff", contactDiff);
       if (contactDiff?.length) {
         draft.contact = contactDiff;
       }

      },
      (patches) => {
        changes.push(...patches);
      }
    );

    //Problem here => default values need to be given to state
    // so the default values need to be excluded from the patch
    let state = { contact: [], address: {} };

    const patch = applyPatches(state, changes);

    console.log("patch", patch);
```

logs changes op

```
contact: Array(1)
0: 11111111
address: Object
pin: 111
email: "something@gmail.com"
```

Hope this helps you in some way

Cheers